# sequelize.js TIMESTAMP not DATETIME

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, timestamp, sequelize.js

In my node.js app I have several models in which I want to define `TIMESTAMP` type columns, including the default timestamps `created_at` and `updated_at`.

According to [sequelize.js' documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/), there is only a `DATE` data type. It creates `DATETIME` columns in MySQL.

Example:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
... // columns
last_login: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
...
}, { // options
        timestamps: true
});
```

Is it possible to generate `TIMESTAMP` columns instead?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just pass in 'TIMESTAMP' string to your type

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
        created_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        allowNull: false
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        allowNull: false
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: this no longer works in sequelize 6, it throws error, anyone know the new method to create `timestamp` columns instead of `datetime` columns?

Comment: It is NOT Sequelize.literal. It MUST BE  sequelize.literal

Answer (score 5):

According to the Sequelize Documentation, you can set a defaultValue of Sequelize.NOW to create a timestamp field.  This has the effect but relies on Sequelize to actually populate the timestamp.  It does not create a "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' attribute on the table.

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
    // default values for dates => current time
    myDate: { 
         type: Sequelize.DATE, 
         defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW 
    }
});
```

So, this does accomplish the end goal of having a timestamp field, but it is controlled through Sequelize and not through the actual database engine.

It also appears to work on databases that do not have a timestamp functionality, so that may be a benefit.

Reference URL:  http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#definition

Comment: i couldn't get this to work.  it kept putting `0000-00-00 00:00` in the db.  sequelize 6 w/ mysql 5.7

Comment: It looks like sequelize 6 has changed to use a slightly different syntax:  DataTypes.DATE and DataTypes.NOW for the values.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#dates

Not sure if that's the issue, but it does appear there are some relevant changes in sequelize 6.

Comment: I tried that as well, but no luck.  Only alucic's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case i create model like below

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
    return sequelize.define('blog', {
        blogId: {
          type: type.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        text: type.STRING,
        createdAt:{
            type: 'TIMESTAMP',
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            allowNull: false
        },
        updatedAt:{
            type: 'TIMESTAMP',
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            allowNull: false
        }
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Working fine with mariadb as of dec-2022

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the moment for creating a timestamp:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.NOW,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      field: 'createdAt'
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
 type: DataTypes.DATE,
```

use below code

```
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did with *sqLite* is extended *DataTypes* with my custom sql logic for *TIMESTAMP* and it worked fine. I'm not 100% sure how the sql syntax should look for MySQL but my guess it's something similar to what I have. Look at example:

```js
function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var util = require('util');
    var timestampSqlFunc = function () {
        var defaultSql = 'DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
        if (this._options && this._options.notNull) {
            defaultSql += ' NOT NULL';
        }
        if (this._options && this._options.onUpdate) {
            // onUpdate logic here:
        }
        return defaultSql;
    };
    DataTypes.TIMESTAMP = function (options) {
        this._options = options;
        var date = new DataTypes.DATE();
        date.toSql = timestampSqlFunc.bind(this);
        if (!(this instanceof DataTypes.DATE)) return date;
        DataTypes.DATE.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    util.inherits(DataTypes.TIMESTAMP, DataTypes.DATE);

    DataTypes.TIMESTAMP.prototype.toSql = timestampSqlFunc;

    var table = sequelize.define("table", {
        /* table fields */
        createdAt: DataTypes.TIMESTAMP,
        updatedAt: DataTypes.TIMESTAMP({ onUpdate: true, notNull: true })
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

};
```

All you need to do for *MySQL* is to change SQL type generation in *timestampSqlFunc* function, so  for example *defaultSql* variable would be `'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`